# solving $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{(a-by^4)t}{c}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I need help in solving the ODE mentioned in the title.

What I've tried is separating and integrating like so:
$$
\int\frac{1}{a-by^4}dy=\int \frac{t}{c} dt
$$
The right hand side is easy to find but the left hand side gets too ugly too quickly. Also, according to an integral calculator I found online, the left side should be:
$$
\ln|by+b^{3/4}\sqrt[\leftroot{2}4]{a}| - \ln|by-b^{3/4}\sqrt[\leftroot{2}4]{a}|+2\arctan(\frac{y\sqrt[\leftroot{2}4]{b}}{\sqrt[\leftroot{2}4]{a}})
$$
From which I do not know how to get $y$ by itself.

Comment: Partial fractions for the LH integral.

Comment: difference of squares

Answer (score 0):

Let $$
I=\int\frac{1}{a-by^4}dy
$$
and $k^4=\frac{a}{b}$, or $k=(\frac{a}{b})^{1/4}$ for simplicity. Then
 $$
I=\frac{1}{b}\int\frac{1}{k^4-y^4}dy=\frac{1}{b}\int\frac{1}{(k^2-y^2)(k^2+y^2)}dy.
$$
$$=\frac{1}{2bk^2}\bigg[\int\frac{1}{k^2-y^2}dy+\int\frac{1}
{k^2+y^2}dy\bigg]\quad\text{(By partial fractions)}.$$ The first integral on the RHS is simplified by trigonometric substitution $y=k\sin\theta$, the second one is $\frac{1}{k}\arctan y$ and so we have 
$$I=\frac{1}{2bk^2}\bigg[\frac{1}{k}\int\frac{d\theta}{\cos\theta}+\frac{1}{k}\arctan y\bigg]=\frac{1}{2bk^2}\bigg[\frac{1}{k}\ln|\sec\theta+\tan \theta|+\frac{1}{k}\arctan y\bigg].$$
$$=\frac{1}{2bk^3}\bigg[\ln|\frac{y+k}{\sqrt{k^2-y^2}}|+\arctan y\bigg]+c_1.$$